# jquery ajax form submit with edit values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a datatable where I have the detail column with an edit button. When the user clicks on the edit am passing the id as a parameter. I am fetching all the values for that id and displaying in the form. Now when I edit the values and submit the form using PUT method it is getting inserted in the table, the values are passing as a parameter and it shows the empty form. How to solve this issue.

HTML:

```
<form class="container" id="myform" name="myform" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="position" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label fw-6">Position</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position" placeholder="Position" required>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="location" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label fw-6">Location</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" required>
       </div>
   </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
       </div>
 </form>
```

PUT Method Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            var parms = {
                position : $("#position").val(),
                location : $("#location").val()
            };
            var par_val;
            var param_id = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            par_val = param_id.get('id');
            console.log(par_val);
            var par_url = par_val;

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/joblists/"+par_val,
                method: 'PUT',
                async: false,
                dataType : "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(parms),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },   
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

GET method script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
          var id_val;
          var params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
           id_val = params.get('id');
          console.log(id_val);
         var url1=id_val;
          $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/joblists/"+id_val,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log(typeof(data));
            $("#position").val(data.position);
            $("#location").val(data.location);

        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
      });

    });
 </script>
```

After submitting the form the page should remain the same with edit form values. only the edited values should be inserted. How to achieve this.

Comment: One solution can be you can reload your page after getting success response i.e `location.reload();`

Comment: @Swati  i have tried but it is showing the empty form

Comment: You are showing values  in  form from  `database` or not ?

Comment: am fetching the values from database. the issue is that values are passing as a parameter in the url after submitting. so i cant able to show the values in the form after submit

Comment: But i didn't find any database code in your form ? try posting your full code

Comment: In the jquery script i have used the PUT method for editing the values for that id

Comment: FYI PUT method always create or overwrite the request .

Comment: @ soorapadman yes i want to overwrite the values for that id. it means EDIT

Comment: where your ajax send its data, a somewhere php script ?

Comment: @MrJ  am not using php am using the API to GET,POST and PUT methods

Comment: so where go your datas ????

Comment: try removing `JSON.stringify()` for sending data instead just add `parms` and add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Hello World how to submit the form without passing the values as a parameter url

Answer (score 0):

$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
..........

Comment: i have tried if i apply this preventDefault() it is not inserting the values

Comment: are you able to get parms in joblists method are not.. if you get parms then check your insert query

Comment: Actually am getting the values and also am inserting. the issue is after submitting the form should remain the same with values. but here after submitting the values are getting passed through the parameter so it shows the empty form

Comment: @lakshmipriya it is because your haven't written any logic to fetch and fill the form again.

Comment: fetch the updated values from db by id and show in input value some simple

Comment: @Cerlin Boss intially i will pass the id and i will fetch the id and fill the form. once the user edit the value and click on submit it will be inserted in the table. Now my issue is clicking on the submit button the values are passing as a parameter so i could not get the id and the form shows empty.

Comment: @lakshmipriya then do this ` Set the button type to button instead of submit and read button click event instead of submit event. This will stop the form from submitting and your ajax code will work`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code in my editor. There are some changes which i made in ajax request, and it now works for me. here is the code. Try it

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var parms = {
                position : $("#position").val(),
                location : $("#location").val()
            };
            var par_val;
            var param_id = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            par_val = param_id.get('id');
            console.log(par_val);
            var par_url = par_val;

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/joblists/"+id_val,
                method: 'POST', //or you can use GET
                dataType : "json", //REMOVED CONTENT TYPE AND ASYNC
                data: {send_obj:JSON.stringify(parms)},  //ADDED OBJECT FOR DATA
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },   
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I found the solution we should use <input type="submit> and on click of submit event.preventDefault()

Comment: Yes Exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding prevent default in form submit handle is enough. You're handling the post request by ajax call.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: if i add it will not submit the form

Comment: Yes exactly. You don't need to submit the form since you're handling your post on your own(ajax)

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 changes in your code.

This code will prevent your page from reloading and also you are not sending the data in proper format.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // 1. Dont reload the page
        var parms = {
            position : $("#position").val(),
            location : $("#location").val()
        };
        var par_val;
        var param_id = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        par_val = param_id.get('id');
        console.log(par_val);
        var par_url = par_val;

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/joblists/"+par_val,
            method: 'PUT',
            async: false,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: parms, // 2. Just send the parms object bcoz you already defined the dataType as json so it will automatically convert it into string.
            success: function(data){
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },
        })
    });
```